# C Linked list - value of pointer changing

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, char

So I'm fairly new to C and pointers and I have a project for school to finish functions for adding to a linked list

this is how it looks:

```
TEMPLOYEE * newEmployee(const char * name, TEMPLOYEE * next)
{
    TEMPLOYEE* head = NULL;
    head = malloc(sizeof(TEMPLOYEE));
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    head -> m_Name = name;
    head -> m_Next = next;
    head -> m_Bak = NULL;
}
```

this works when entering name as a string for example `a = newEmployee ( "Peter", a );`
but when I try to add using a temporary value the m_Name in like this

```
strncpy ( tmp, "Victoria", sizeof ( tmp ) );
a = newEmployee ( tmp, a );
strncpy ( tmp, "Peter", sizeof ( tmp ) );
a = newEmployee ( tmp, a );
```

the list will change with the value so it will have two employees with the name Peter instead of Peter and Victoria and I can't find how to do this. Any help is welcome.

Comment: you're using the same pointer (tmp) while creating list nodes, so they both point to the same location. you overwrite "Victoria" with "Peter", so both nodes point to "Peter"

Comment: You need to allocate separate space for each name the same way you did for the list.

Comment: Also, your first routine is missing`return head`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function `newEmployee()`, you are doing:

```
head -> m_Name = name;
```

In both `newEmployee()` call, you are passing `tmp`:

```
a = newEmployee ( tmp, a );
a = newEmployee ( tmp, a );
```

So, the `name` pointer of both the nodes are pointing to same location `tmp` which contains the name. If you make any change in the value of `tmp`, it will be reflected in both.

The in memory view would be something like this:

```
---------------------
|m_Name|m_Next|m_Bak|
---------------------
    | 
    \/    tmp
   -----------
   | Peter   |
   -----------
    /\
    |
---------------------
|m_Name|m_Next|m_Bak|
---------------------

// Both the node m_Name is pointing to same location.
// Make any change in tmp and the changes will reflect in both the pointers
// as they are pointing to same location.
```

To solve this problem, you should allocate memory to `m_Name` and copy the `tmp` to it. You can use `strdup()` to resolve this issue. In the `newEmployee()`, replace this:

```
head -> m_Name = name;
```

with this:

```
head -> m_Name = strdup(name);
```

The [`strdup()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) function returns a pointer to a new string which is a duplicate of the string passed to it. strdup() allocates a memory for the new string and returns its pointer. Make sure to free it using `free()` once you are done with it. Note that `strdup()` is not part of the `C` Standard.

The `newEmployee()` function return type is `TEMPLOYEE *` but you are not returning anything from this function if the `malloc` is successful. Also, if `malloc` fails for some reason you are returning integer constant `1` from it which is incorrect. Instead, you should return `NULL` in case of failure.

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what I needed